# How to loop through var to populate a DropDown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, petapoco

I am using ASP.NET/C# 4.0 with PetaPoco Micro ORM.

PetaPoco code retrieves a list of Years in a **var**. Now I want to populate an ASP.NET DropDown Control with the items in this **var**.

Does PetaPoco provide something to do this in less code? Alternatively, how can I loop through the **var** and add items in the DropDown?

```
    var db = new PetaPoco.Database("myConnection");
    var fy = new fy_master();

    string Query = "SELECT fyperiod FROM fy_master ORDER BY fy_id desc";
    var result = db.Execute(Query);
```

Comment: You're missing the point of what `var` is. It isn't a type that has it's own interface, it is whatever you assign to it.

Comment: A `var` is not a type. It's a keyword for when you don't know or don't care about the type, but the system knows the type. It infers it during compile time and with Intellisense you can hover over the var and see what it becomes!

Comment: Actually I tried adding a List but that is again an overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Petapoco Documentation](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) `Execute` is similar to `ExecuteNonQuery` which you can't use if you want to select items. You must use `Fetch` command to return a list of POCOs.

Here is a [discussion on populating combo box](http://forums.asp.net/t/1778710.aspx/1?How%20to%20populate%20Obout%20ComboBox%20using%20PetaPoco%20Query%20). You should be able to follow a similar approach to fill in ASP.NET DropDownList